# Change ctime, mtime and atime of a windows file?

Tags: python, windows, time, pywin32

I use:

```
ctime = (datetimes[0])
mtime = (datetimes[1])
atime = (datetimes[2])
# handle datetime.datetime parameters
if isinstance( ctime, datetime.datetime ) :
    ctime = time.mktime( ctime.timetuple() )
if isinstance( mtime, datetime.datetime ) :
    mtime = time.mktime( mtime.timetuple() )
if isinstance( atime, datetime.datetime ) :
    atime = time.mktime( atime.timetuple() )
# adjust for day light savings
now = time.localtime()
ctime += 3600 * (now.tm_isdst - time.localtime(ctime).tm_isdst)
mtime += 3600 * (now.tm_isdst - time.localtime(mtime).tm_isdst)
atime += 3600 * (now.tm_isdst - time.localtime(atime).tm_isdst)
# change time stamps
winfile = win32file.CreateFile(
    path_completo_actual, win32con.GENERIC_WRITE,
    win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
    None, win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
    win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, None)

win32file.SetFileTime( winfile, Time(int(ctime)), Time(int(atime)), Time(int(mtime)) )
winfile.close()
```

But I can't use `pywintypes`, it says: `pywintypes has no Time member`.
I have `import pywintypes`:

```
from pywintypes import Time
```

Comment: Something must be messed-up with your installation of `pywin32`, because I can do a `from pywintypes import Time` after upgrading to the latest version, build 227 for Python 3.8 — try reinstalling it.

Comment: FYI, you only need metadata access, not data access (i.e. generic write access), and thus you do not need a data-access sharing mode. It's important to never request more access than is required. The call to open the file should be `win32file.CreateFile(path_completo_actual, ntsecuritycon.FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, 0, None, win32file.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, None)`.

Comment: Probably you're running Python 2, but I haven't checked. In Python 3, you can pass datetime objects directly to `win32file.SetFileTime`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help
tree days in this problem, and probably is VS Code or Pylint

[[image: In Python CMD][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMzZp.jpg)

[image: In VS Code]